# React-Select/Async promiseOptions signature causes a Typescript error

Tags: typescript, react-select

I am using [code based off the Promise-based example in the React-Select Async documentation](https://react-select.com/async#loading-asynchronously). The function fires off a request for the API to search contacts by email.

```
/**
     * Searches for contacts that match string
     * @param email
     * @returns
     */
    const findContacts = (email: string): Promise<OptionType[]> =>
        getPersonByEmail(email)?.then((result: any[]) =>
            result.map(c => {
                return { label: c.emailAddress, value: c.emailAddress };
            }))
            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
    const promiseOptions = (inputValue: string) =>
        new Promise<OptionType[]>((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(findContacts(inputValue));
            }, 1000);
        });
```

```
type OptionType = {
    value: string;
    label: string;
  };
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeScript error in /builds/org/admin/src/components/FormComponents/EmailAutoComplete.formcomponent.tsx(80,25):
75Type '(inputValue: string) => Promise<OptionType[] | null>' is not assignable to type '(inputValue: string, callback: (options: OptionsOrGroups<OptionType, GroupBase<OptionType>>) => void) => void | Promise<OptionsOrGroups<...>>'.
76  Type 'Promise<OptionType[] | null>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<OptionsOrGroups<OptionType, GroupBase<OptionType>>>'.
77    Type 'Promise<OptionType[] | null>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<OptionsOrGroups<OptionType, GroupBase<OptionType>>>'.
78      Type 'OptionType[] | null' is not assignable to type 'OptionsOrGroups<OptionType, GroupBase<OptionType>>'.
79        Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'readonly (OptionType | GroupBase<OptionType>)[]'.  TS2322
80    78 |                         isClearable
81    79 |                         createOptionPosition="first" // Move create option to the top
82  > 80 |                         loadOptions={promiseOptions} // Promise that loads results
83       |                         ^
84    81 |                         formatCreateLabel={userInput => `Use ${userInput}`}
85    82 |                         isLoading={isLoading}
86    83 |                         openMenuOnClick={false}
87
```